# Join the line if its startswith plus sign and next line starts with Solaris

Tags: python-3.6

Join the line if its startswith plus sign and next line starts with Solaris then only joins the two lines into one.

Data looks like as below on the file, Just looking  for the ideas..

i asked it because data is not consistent in terms of the pattern i shown above.

```
   ++++++++ host01 ++++++++
                              Solaris 10 10/08 s10s_u6wos_07b SPARC
   ++++++++ host02 ++++++++
                              Solaris 10 10/08 s10s_u6wos_07b SPARC    
    ++++++++ host21 ++++++++
    ssh: connect to host host011 port 22: Connection timed out
    ssh: connect to host host012 port 22: Connection timed out
```

i tried below but not resulting anything..

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
stat = ""
with open("sunfor", mode="r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if stat.startswith("+") and line.endswith("SPARC"):
            print(stat.strip())
            print(line)
```

Even tried with..

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
with open("sunfor", mode="r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("+") and line.startswith("Solaris"):
            print(line)
```

Comment: stat will always be empty in your code sample

Comment: @AnyMoose, thnx for the inputs, thats what i want to understand as a newbie learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting stat to be the last line it can now compare correctly.
Then print result as a concat using the plus sign

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
stat = ""
with open("sunfor", mode="r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if stat.startswith("+") and line.endswith("SPARC"):
            print(stat.strip()+line)
        stat = line
```

Result

> ++++++++ host01 ++++++++Solaris 10 10/08 s10s_u6wos_07b SPARC
>
> ++++++++ host02 ++++++++Solaris 10 10/08 s10s_u6wos_07b SPARC